# How to remove multipart/form-data;boundary from WebClient.UploadFile?

Tags: c#, http-headers, youtube-api

I'm trying to upload an image to a Google API.  I'm using the .net WebClient.UploadFile.  When I do the upload the request includes a Content-Type multipart/form-data;boundary= in the request and I'm getting the following error.

> "Content-Type
>   multipart/form-data;boundary=---------------------8d0738def5b9322 is
>   not a valid input type"

Is there any way to remove this from the request or do I need to used a different upload method?

```
 var client = new WebClient();
 client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _accessToken);
 client.Headers.Add("GData-Version", "2");
 client.Headers.Add("X-GData-Key", "key=" + _developerKey);
 client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
 client.UploadFile(URL_PROFILE_UPLOAD_FEED.Replace("default", channelId), filePath);
```

Request format required by documentation.

POST /feeds/api/partners/default/images/IMAGE_TYPE HTTP/1.1
Host: uploads.gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

BINARY_FILE_DATA

Comment: Try UploadData method of WebClient instead of UploadFile.

Comment: @VladimirFrolov That did it.  If you want to post that as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `UploadData` method of `WebClient` class instead of `UploadFile`.

Comment: For people who may want to know getting bytes[] from a file $bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("file_path")